# Matlab find the best constants for a fitting model

Tags: matlab, optimization

Please find the data in the link below, or if you can send me your private email, I can send you the data

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5353938/test_matlab_lefou.xlsx

In the excel sheet, the first column is y, the second is x and the third is t, I hope this will make things much more clear, and many thanks for the help.

I need to use the following model because it is the one that fits best my data, but what I don't know is how to find the best values of a and b, that will allow me to get the best fit, (I can attach a file if you need the values), I already have the values of y, x and t:

y= a*sqrt(x).exp(b.t)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have problems how to get those values (so is the problem mathematically) or is your problem to realize it in matlab? Because right now your question seems to be about how to solve such a mathematical problem. IF that is the case check out some pages about least square distance ([wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) ) or about how to minimalize the square distance

Comment: My problem is how to find these values in Matlab

Comment: Then in my opinion you should edit your post to contain what you have done, what it is that you wish to implement (as code or at least as pseudocode) and what it is you are really struggling with. Cause right now this looks like: "hey I want sth. do it for me"

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean this, it is just that I am not sure on how to do it.Let's say I have the following array of values, so how do I proceed to plot the graph when I don't have a & b and how to get the best optimized values of a & b.                                             y=testmatlablefou(:,1);
x=testmatlablefou(:,2);
t=testmatlablefou(:,3);

Comment: I can try to do this for example                                      'y1=sqrt(x)*exp(t)' and then compare y to y1 to try to get a & b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the dependency on the curve fitting toolbox, this problem can also be solved by using `fminsearch`. I first generate some data, which you already have but didn't share with us. An initial guess on the parameters a and b must be made (`p0`). Then I do the optimiziation by minizmizing the squared errors between data and fit resulting in the vector `p_fit`, which contains the optimized parameters for a and b. In the end, the result is visualized.

```
% ----- Generating some data for x, y and t (which you already got)
N = 10; % num of data points
x = linspace(0,5,N);
t = linspace(0,10,N);

% random parameters
a = rand()*5; % a between 0 and 5
b = (rand()-1); % b between -1 and 0
y = a*sqrt(x).*exp(b*t) + rand(size(x))*0.1; % noisy data

% ----- YOU START HERE WITH YOUR PROBLEM -----
% put x and t into a 2 row matrix for simplicity
D(1,:) = x;
D(2,:) = t;

% create model function with parameters p(1) = a and p(2) = b
model = @(p, D) p(1)*sqrt(D(1,:)).*exp(p(2)*D(2,:));
e = @(p) sum((y - model(p,D)).^2); % minimize squared errors
p0 = [1,-1]; % an initial guess (positive a and probably negative b for a decay)
[p_fit, r1] = fminsearch(e, p0); % Optimize 


% ----- VISUALIZATION ----
figure
plot(x,y,'ko')
hold on
X = linspace(min(x), max(x), 100);
T = linspace(min(t), max(t), 100);
plot(X, model(p_fit, [X; T]), 'r--')
legend('data', sprintf('fit: y(t,x) = %.2f*sqrt(x)*exp(%.2f*t)', p_fit))
```

The result can look like [image: this]

**UPDATE AFTER MANY MANY COMMENTS**

Your data are column vectors, my solution used row vectors. The error occured when the errorfunction tryed to compute the difference of a column vector (`y`) and a row-vector (result of the model-function). Easy hack: make them all to row vectors and use my approach. The result is: a = 0.5296 and b = 0.0013.
However, the Optimization depends on the initial guess `p0`, you might want to play around with it a little bit.

```
clear variables
load matlab.mat

% put x and t into a 2 row matrix for simplicity
D(1,:) = x;
D(2,:) = t;
y = reshape(y, 1, length(y)); % <-- also y is a row vector, now

% create model function with parameters p(1) = a and p(2) = b
model = @(p, D) p(1)*sqrt(D(1,:)).*exp(p(2)*D(2,:));
e = @(p) sum((y - model(p,D)).^2); % minimize squared errors
p0 = [1,0]; % an initial guess (positive a and probably negative b for a decay)
[p_fit, r1] = fminsearch(e, p0); % Optimize 

% p_fit = nlinfit(D, y, model, p0) % as a working alternative with dependency on the statistics toolbox

% ----- VISUALIZATION ----
figure
plot(x,y,'ko', 'markerfacecolor', 'black', 'markersize',5)
hold on
X = linspace(min(x), max(x), 100);
T = linspace(min(t), max(t), 100);
plot(X, model(p_fit, [X; T]), 'r-', 'linewidth', 2)
legend('data', sprintf('fit: y(t,x) = %.2f*sqrt(x)*exp(%.2f*t)', p_fit))
```

The result doesn't look too satisfying though. But that mainly is because of your data. Have a look here: [image]

Comment: Please can you check the data in the comment above, I didn't share the data because I didn't find a way to attach the file

Comment: while trying to apply your method, on my data, there is an error by matlab stating the following : Error in fminsearch (line 191) fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

Comment: Please can you explain to me why you generated the X  and T, and why 100 values for each one of them? Thanks

Comment: @lefou I will not try to figure out, which of the ``x``, ``t`` and ``y`` I should use, unless you provide clean data, which means all data vectors are of the same length. It would be best to edit your question and put the dataset in the question, not in some comment. Also, I cannot reproduce the error you described AND that clearly isn't the full error traceback. You want help so please be as cooperative as possilble. The part with ``X`` and ``T`` is just for visualization. You get smoother lines with more points and the model function can be evaluated at all pairs of ``x`` and ``t``.

Comment: Please it is possible to attach a file, if yes how?

Comment: @ Nras I edited the question again, please see the question above, where I posted a link so you can download my data (it's an excel file), thanking you in advance

Comment: @lefou I do not work with xlsx files and the Matlab Import Wizard throws an error: Warning: File contains uninterpretable data. Please don't make life so hard for people willing to help. Just give a small sample as you did in the comment, but make sure all vectors are of the same length. If the error occurs only for larger samples, make sure to give an example with random numbers or stuff.

Comment: @lefou one more hint: if you have access to the statistics toolbox, you can avoid the ``fminsearch`` part (and the part defining the error-function e) by writing: ``p_fit = nlinfit(D, y, model, p0)``. It does give the same ``p_fit`` for my example as the version with ``fminsearch`` does. Maybe test it for your real data and see if it helps.

Comment: thanks I have access to the toolbox, I tried the solution you mentioned above, and it is giving me the following error :                                                              Error using nlinfit>checkFunVals (line 612)
The function you provided as the MODELFUN input has returned Inf or NaN values.

Error in nlinfit>LMfit (line 559)
    if funValCheck && ~isfinite(sse), checkFunVals(r); end

Error in nlinfit (line 276)
        [beta,J,~,cause,fullr] = LMfit(X,yw, modelw,beta,options,verbose,maxiter);

Comment: @Nars here is the link where you can try my data :                                                                             http://www.filedropper.com/matlab_2

Comment: @lefou See the update in the answer. As a very last comment: It is quite exhausting when you are not properly responding to questions in comments. It was a minor update (realize difference of row-vectors vs column-vectors as input), which now took you a day. It really could have been easier. For future questions: please make everything as clear as neccesseray and provide some data, when needed. You are more likely to get a good answer then.

Comment: thanks a lot and it is the first time I try to post something here and it was a bit tiring for me because I didn't a way from the beginning to attach the document with the data. Anyways many many thanks for the precious help

Answer (score 1):

With the `cftool`-command (curve fitting toolbox) you can fit to your own functions, returning the variables that you need (a,b). Make sure your x-data and y-data are in separate variables. you can also specify weights for your measurements.

Comment: does the cftool give me the values of a & b?

Comment: Please can you give me a hint on how to do it? thanks

Comment: 'y=[13.2563
14.9891
24.0338
15.4405
27.1803
16.972
14.8228
15.867
1.81011
0.50918
16.6698
10.0985
9.16819
10.5727
3.49259
2.0371
1.11696
0.07645
0.16101
-0.04732
-0.05736];                                                   x=[25.7
26
25.9
26.5
26.5
26.4
26.2
26.6
26.6
26.4
26.3
26.1
25.8
25.6
24.7
23.8
22.9
22.5
21.7
21.1
20.2
20];                                                   t=[1818.824
1893.31
1934.15
1921.384
1892.088
1891.962
1838.306
1737.683
1594.182
1394.7
1186.022
839.6656
786.6523
752.3392
506.787
349.4027
113.1767
39.3187
5.880522
0.8564087
0.8591992
0.8583118];'

Comment: the above is an example of few values, in fact I have for each array around 3000 values

Comment: @lefou Please make sure the vectors for ``y``, ``x`` and ``t`` are of the same size.

Comment: @Nras yes they are, but probably I missed one of them while posting, because of the limited number of characters in the post.

Comment: @Nras while trying to apply your method, on my data, there is an error by matlab stating the following :                    Error in fminsearch (line 191)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

Comment: @lefou I guess your original data has vectors which are of equal length. But if you provide data, make sure it is usable as is and doesn't require the other users to guess what they should do now in order to be able to use the data.