# Use of excel solver function in matlab for multiple optimization

Tags: matlab, math, modeling

I have multiple sets of `x` and `y`. One of them is as follows:

```
x = [  1.4   15.15    49.395    98.8  151.475    184.41    230.51    259.2 ]
y = [ 12.15  21.2125  25.15125  25.3   24.63125   28.8975   29.8725   35.2 ]
```

In addition to that, I have two parameters `k` and `n` which are related to `x` as follows

```
q = k.* x^-n
```

I have three functions:

```
e = q.*q - y.*y

f = q-y

g = (q-y)^1/2
```

First I want to minimize function `e` related to `y` as follows:

```
e = q.*q - y.*y
```

Afterwards I want to simultaneously minimize function `f`, followed by `g`.

Comment: Please show an attempt at the Matlab implementation of this, quote your code and explain what your problems are relative to your code. That way it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab find the best constants for a fitting model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252870/matlab-find-the-best-constants-for-a-fitting-model)

Answer (score 1):

There are several flaws in your code.

1. your "functions" are not functions, but vectors. --> function handle
2. your minimization "function" f makes no sense, as positive and negative errors can cancel each other out --> absolute values
3. your minimization "function" g can produce imaginary numbers, as q-y can get negative --> absolute values

Here comes some code, which techically does, what you want. Also i added the function `h`, which minimizes the sum of squared errors, which is the default minimization function

```
%// Data
x = [  1.4   15.15    49.395    98.8  151.475    184.41    230.51    259.2 ];
y = [ 12.15  21.2125  25.15125  25.3   24.63125   28.8975   29.8725   35.2 ];

%// create model function q with parameters p(1) = k and p(2) = n
q = @(p, x) p(1)*x.^(-p(2));

%// create the desired error-functions for minimization
e = @(p) sum((y.^2 - q(p, x)).^2); %// minimization function
f = @(p) sum(abs(y - q(p, x))); %// better sum over absolute values
g = @(p) sum(sqrt(abs(q(p, x) - y))); %// better take square roots of absolute values
h = @(p) sum((q(p, x) - y).^2); %// default minimizaton function

p0 = [1, -0.5]; % an initial guess 

[p_fit_e, r_e] = fminsearch(e, p0) % Optimize 
[p_fit_f, r_f] = fminsearch(f, p0) % Optimize 
[p_fit_g, r_g] = fminsearch(g, p0) % Optimize 
[p_fit_h, r_h] = fminsearch(h, p0) % Optimize 

%// visualization
figure
plot(x,y,'ko')
hold on
X = linspace(min(x), max(x), 100);

plot(X, q(p_fit_e, X), 'r-')
plot(X, q(p_fit_f, X), 'g-')
plot(X, q(p_fit_g, X), 'b-')
plot(X, q(p_fit_h, X), 'k-')
```

The optimization for you error-function `e` seems to fail.
Please note that for the default case of function `h` you can also use `nlinfit` like so:

```
p_fit_h_nlinfit = nlinfit(x, y, q, p0);
```

which in this case produces the same result:

```
p_fit_h_nlinfit =

12.3018   -0.1675

p_fit_h =

12.3018   -0.1675
```

Comment: Thanks Nras for solving this problem to me

Comment: if i want to bound my constant n from zero to one (0 to 1). how can I modify source code

Comment: @DEEPAKGUSAIN For opimizations with conditions, have a look at ``fmincon`` (requires the optimization toolbox).

Comment: Thanks @Nras for your kind help and insight

Answer (score 0):

```
@Nras I have modified the syntax and thanks for your help
```

%// Data
    x = [  1.4   15.15    49.395    98.8  151.475    184.41    230.51    259.2 ];
    y = [ 12.15  21.2125  25.15125  25.3   24.63125   28.8975   29.8725   35.2 ];

%// create model function q with parameters p(1) = k and p(2) = n
    q = @(p, x) p(1)*x.^(-p(2));

%// create the desired error-functions for minimization
    e = @(p) sum((y.^2 - q(p, x)).^2); %// minimization function
    f = @(p) sum(abs(y - q(p, x))); %// better sum over absolute values
    g = @(p) sum(sqrt(abs(q(p, x) - y))); %// better take square roots of absolute values
    h = @(p) sum((q(p, x) - y).^2); %// default minimizaton function

```
p0 = [1, 0.5]; % an initial guess 

A = [];
b=[];
Aeq = [];
beq=[];
lb = [-inf,0];
ub = [inf,1];
nonlcon= []
options = optimset('Display','iter','Algorithm','active-set');
options.MaxFunEvals = 100000;
options.MaxIter = 100000

[p_fit_e, r_e] = fmincon(e,p0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options) % Optimize 
[p_fit_f, r_f] = fmincon(f, p0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options) % Optimize 
[p_fit_g, r_g] = fmincon(g, p0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options) % Optimize 
[p_fit_h, r_h] = fmincon(h,p0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options)% Optimize

[minVal minInd] = min(r_e)
[minVal minInd] = min(r_f)
[minVal minInd] = min(r_g)
[minVal minInd] = min(r_h)

e1 =  p_fit_e(1)*x.^(-p_fit_e(2));
f1 =  p_fit_f(1)*x.^(-p_fit_f(2));
g1 =  p_fit_g(1)*x.^(-p_fit_g(2));
h1 =  p_fit_h(1)*x.^(-p_fit_h(2));


figure(1)
plot(x,e1)
hold on
plot(x,y)

figure(2)
plot(x,f1)
hold on
plot(x,y)

figure(3)
plot(x,g1)
hold on
plot(x,y)

figure(4)
plot(x,h1)
hold on
plot(x,y)
```